# How to avoid representing instances in alphabetical order using OWLAPI

Tags: java, arrays, owl, ontology, owl-api

I have created Ontology using OWL-API. I have added Instances using an array.But Ontology represents it in alphabetical order not according to the order which I have included in the array. As a result of this the other instances're mismatched.

```
       String Item1_List[]={"PencilBox","Box"};        
       int Item1_QuntList[] = {5,4};
       Set<OWLAxiom> axioms = new HashSet<OWLAxiom>();
       for( int i=0 ; i<Item1_List.length ; i++){  
       axioms.add(df.getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom(Item1_Name, Item1,Item1_List[i])); }

      for( int i=0 ; i<Item1_QuntList.length ; i++){
      axioms.add(df.getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom(Item1_Quantity,Item1,Item1_QuntList[i])); }

      manager.addAxioms(ontology2, axioms);
```

And this is the output Ontology.

```
<!-- Item1 -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item"/>
    <Item1_Name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Box</Item1_Name>
    <Item1_Name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">PencilBox</Item1_Name>
    <Item1_Quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">4</Item1_Quantity>
    <Item1_Quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">5</Item1_Quantity>
    <has rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/imesha/ontologies/2015/7/untitled-ontology-26#Item2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Instance "Box" comes before the instance "PencilBox". How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ontology is defined as a set of axioms. The order is not specified and it is not semantically relevant. The owl api tries to keep it invariant when ontologies are edited, to reduce changes to files that might be held in source control systems - git repositories for example.

Why do you need the instances to be represented in a certain order?

Edit: adding an example to follow up on the comments.

The `Pencil` and `Box` strings appear to represent individuals with attached properties, e.g., a `quantity` property. An alternative modelling that does not rely on order to attach quantity to individual can be obtained with this code:

Code:

```
    OWLIndividual Item1 = df.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create("http://test.com/test#Item1"));
    OWLObjectProperty Item1_Name = df.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create("http://test.com/test#Item"));
    OWLDataProperty Item1_Quantity = df.getOWLDataProperty(IRI.create("http://test.com/test#Quantity"));
    OWLIndividual Item1_List[] = { df.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create("http://test.com/test#PencilBox")), df
        .getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create("http://test.com/test#Box")) };
    int Item1_QuntList[] = { 5, 4 };
    Set<OWLAxiom> axioms = new HashSet<OWLAxiom>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Item1_List.length; i++) {
        axioms.add(df.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(Item1_Name, Item1, Item1_List[i]));
        axioms.add(df.getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom(Item1_Quantity, Item1_List[i], Item1_QuntList[i]));
    }
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="owlapi:ontology#ont1#"
 xml:base="owlapi:ontology#ont1"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:test="http://test.com/test#"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="owlapi:ontology#ont1"/>
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://test.com/test#Item"/>
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://test.com/test#Quantity"/>
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://test.com/test#Box">
    <test:Quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">4</test:Quantity>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://test.com/test#Item1">
    <test:Item rdf:resource="http://test.com/test#Box"/>
    <test:Item rdf:resource="http://test.com/test#PencilBox"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://test.com/test#PencilBox">
    <test:Quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">5</test:Quantity>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my code, I need the Item1_List[] Array Items display parallel with Item1_QuntList[] Array. That means PencilBox quantity is 4 and box Quantity is 5. But the output shows the order in the otherway. Box quantity is 5 and PencilBox quantity is 4.For the query purpose, it should be in the given array order. Otherwise how the quantities of each items can be identify?  I need a help for this.

Comment: From your description, 5 needs to be an assertion on a Box individual, and 4 an assertion on a PencilBox individual. I'll put an example in an answer.

Comment: How to represent this type of question in ontology,
Sunil had 12 pencils. He gave 6 pencils to his brother. How many pencils does Sunil have?. I think ontology can represent the first 2 statements

Comment: The pattern underneath any such questions is the same as account keeping: an initial state without pencils, and transactions where pencils are added or removed, with an indication of where they came from or where they went, and a timestamp of when this happened. Each transaction is an individual with a property for each of the mentioned features, and Sunil and his brother (better, their accounts) can be linked to as many transactions as required. This allows the balance to be computed at any point, and keeps full history of what happened. Can be easily used for pencils, apples, or money.

Comment: Got your point. Im using it to any questions which are same as the mentioned previously. Same type of question can be asked in different patterns.

Comment: For example,
Sunil had 12 pencils. He gave 6 pencils to his brother. How many pencils does Sunil have?

Sunil had 12 pencils. He gave half the pencils to his brother. How many pencils does Sunil have?
Sunil had 12 pencils. His brother brought half of the pencils form Sunil. How many pencils does Sunil owns now?

Sunil had 12 pencils. Nimal gave 6 pencils to Sunil. How many pencils does Sunil have?
Nimal gave 6 pencils to Sunil. Sunil had 12 pencils. How many pencils does Sunil have?